Alternator starts arter hitting gas
I have a Citroen C3, 1.4 year 2002.
This car gives me headache. I have problem with alternator that doesn’t start until I hit the gas. I have changed battery, changed ground cable, changed alternator and also the belt two times. One original and then one from AutoDoc with expertise help. And still not working perfect condition. When I start the car, I need to hit the gas and then alternator works until I turn of the car. Tried to reset BSI without any results. Even mechanic is tired of the car because they can’t find the issue. Their conclusion was it is something with electricity.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You are saying there's a problem with the alternator, but you don't really describe what it's doing or not doing. Could you please edit your question and include more detail about it, please?
